# Extract certain portion of multiline string using Python re

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have been trying to extract the SQL query in a multi-line text but all the time I am getting wrong output.

How to get the text between one or three quotes?

Note: there can be anything before and after first complete quotes `''`, `""`, `""""""`, `''''''` and I am only interested finding the first text between the quotes.

```py
import re

cell_text = """\
#%%sql
q = \"\"\"
select 
name, breed, sum(weight) over (partition by breed order by name) as running_total_weight
from cats 
order by breed, name
\"\"\"

f(q)
"""
print(cell_text)
```

My attempt:

```
pat = """.*select(.*)['"].*"""
out = re.findall(pat,cell_text,flags=re.M)[0]
sql = 'select ' + out
print(sql)

# I am getting empty outputs for re.findall instead of text there.
```

Required output:

```
input
----

#%%sql
q = """
select 
name, breed, sum(weight) over (partition by breed order by name) as running_total_weight
from cats 
order by breed, name
"""

f(q)

output
------

select 
name, breed, sum(weight) over (partition by breed order by name) as running_total_weight
from cats 
order by breed, name


input
-----
#%%sql
q = "select * from cats;"

f(q)

output
-------
select * from cats;

input
-----
q = 'select * from cats limit 2'

output
------
select * from cats limit 2
```

Comment: I think the problem is that `.*` ends up matching the quotes so it can't match, using `[^"]` might be relevant?

Comment: 1) You need dot all flag. 2) You forgot to match quotes. 3) You don't need `select` or those three dot-stars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `DOTALL` or `(?s)` mode like this:

```
>>> print (re.findall(r'(?s)"""(.*?)"""', cell_text)[0])

select
name, breed, sum(weight) over (partition by breed order by name) as running_total_weight
from cats
order by breed, name
```

You could also use `flags` parameter in `re.findall`:

```
re.findall(r'"""(.*?)"""', cell_text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

---

**Edit:** Note that to match all single or triple quoted text you may use this regex with alternation:

```
r"""\"\"\"(.*?)\"\"\"|'''(.*?)'''|"(.*?)"|'(.*?)'"""
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GVw79q/1)

Comment: I tried `re.findall(pat,cell_text,flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)[0]` but get two extra quotes `""` in the end, how to avoid that extra trailing quotes?

Comment: @astro123 To get the first match, use `re.search`. `re.findall` returns multiple matches.

Comment: Pattern CAN NOT be  `pat=r'"""(.*?)"""'` since the query can be `q = "myquery"`, `q = """ myquery"""`  i.e. anything between single and triple quotes. not only triple double quotes.

Comment: It is a fix for the code you've shown in question where you are using `pat = """.*select(.*)['"].*"""`. Please provide some sample for single quote matching also

Comment: To match all these case you may use this regex: `r"""\"\"\"(.+?)\"\"\"|'''(.+?)'''|"(.+?)"|'(.+?)'"""`